# Analytic tool for API based application

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing an application which is based on SAAS and exposing services as API. I would like to develop effective analytic platform for API usage, prediction of usage and cost estimation etc. Is there any analytic service which I can leverage like Google Analytic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API usage is typically tracked with internal (self-hosted) tools like [statsd + graphite](http://mat.github.com/statsd-railscamp2011-slides).
Etsy uses this combination as well:
http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/

Another alternative that appears to be in beta is [StatHat](http://www.stathat.com/).

Typically these solutions don't allow much slicing/dicing of the data, but they help you track overall volume and usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out a heavier API management solution like [Mashery](http://www.mashery.com/)